# Using unique_ptr as a method parameter - Pros and cons

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I noticed that if i have the following:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
};

class Wobble
{
public:
    void SetWibble( unique_ptr<Foo> foo )
    {
        this->wibble = move( foo );
    }

    // I like returning a ref as it gives control to 
    // the user of my framework over recieving a & or a copy
    Foo& GetWibble() 
    {
        return *wibble;
    }

    unique_ptr<Foo> wibble;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<Wobble> wobble;    

    unique_ptr<Foo> foo( new Foo() ); // Look here   
    foo->something = ...;
    foo->something1 = ...;
    foo->something2 = ...;

    wobble->SetWibble( move( foo ) );

    return 0;
}
```

...when i declare `foo`, I have a nice `Foo` object.. and when i `move` its ownership into the `wobble` instance, foo is now empty in the `int _tmain` scope.

I quite liked this as I thought it was removing memory and clearing the pointer from the `int _tmain` scope... which in my current context should not need to be fiddled with any more... As opposed to this:

```
// ...
void SetWibble( Foo& foo )
{
    this->wibble = foo;
}
// ...

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<Wobble> wobble;  

    Foo foo;
    foo.something = ...;
    foo.something1 = ...;
    foo.something2 = ...;

    wobble->SetWibble( foo );

    return 0;
}
```

Which still keeps a reference to that variable inside the scope.

**Q:**

1. Is what i have said above correct?
2. I am wondering if there are any benefits over using unique_ptr and not using unique_ptr here apart from the ones i have pointed out?

Comment: You would probably find this interesting: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: I am going to read this properly this time, I think i have been directed tot his before...

Comment: You forget that in one case you're using the heap and in the other the stack, the choice depends on the application.

Comment: In your second example, I assume the member variable `wibble` in `Wobble` is a value, not a reference? I.e `Wobble::SetWibble` takes a copy?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between your two examples is not the use of `std::unique_ptr` but your use of dynamic memory allocation vs allocation on the stack.

It is generally preferable to allocate objects on the stack. You will avoid the cost of a dynamic memory allocation and the unnecessary indirection of a pointer (I can't see any reason not to allocate `Wobble` on the stack for a start).

If you are just concerned about having a variable in your scope perhaps you could extract out the creation of `Foo` to a separate function:

```
Foo createFoo() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.something = ...;
    foo.something1 = ...;
    foo.something2 = ...;
    return foo;
}

int main() {
    Wobble wobble;
    wobble.SetWibble(createFoo());
}
```

Alternatively, if `Foo` is movable, you can move it directly instead of moving a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`:

```
int main() {
    Wobble wobble;

    Foo foo;
    foo.something = ...;
    foo.something1 = ...;
    foo.something2 = ...;

    wobble.SetWibble(std::move(foo));
}
```

If you do this you might want to optimize `SetWibble` for r-value references. Even if there is no particular efficiency advantage of moving `foo` it at least documents that the variable should not be fiddled with any more.

If `Foo` is not movable and is expensive to copy then yes, then there might be a reason to allocate memory dynamically. And, yes if you are going to allocate memory dynamically it is good practice to manage that memory with `std::unique_ptr`.

**Off-topic:**

- In your first example, be careful of dereferencing `wibble` in `GetWibble`. Do you have any guarantee that `wibble` is not null? It could never have been set, or it could have been explicitly set to `nullptr` Perhaps this is a precondition of calling `GetWibble` but it is an example of how the extra indirection of a pointer can add complications.
- In your second example it would be more idiomatic for `SetWibble` to take a const reference.